# Получение id предыдущего INSERT запроса

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток. Есть две таблицы: родительская таблица family содержит такую структуру:

```
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 name varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

дочерняя таблица child, с такой структурой:

```
 id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 name varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
 numberFamily int(4) NOT NULL default 0,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
```

Какой должен быть запрос что бы данные записывались в обе таблицы? Но при записи в таблицу child, поле  numberFamily соответствовало id  из последней внесенной записи в таблицу family?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно использовать `LAST_INSERT_ID()` примерно [вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837990/last-insert-id-mysql).

```
INSERT INTO family (name) VALUES ('test'); 
SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO child (numberFamily,name) VALUES (@last_id_in_table1, 'test2');
```

И потребуется изменить структуру второй таблицы, чтобы `numberFamily` была той же размерности, что и `id` в первой, иначе однажды словишь ошибки.

Comment: MySQL уже давно не смотрит на число указанное у Int-а. Можете сами проверить. А вот флаг unsigned я думаю не помешал бы...

Comment: @zig1375 "Давно" понятие растяжимое, а указывать размерность всё-таки лучше одинаковую, for the best practice.

Comment: Я подключил как вы написали, что интересно теперь через phpMyAdmin отрабатывается запрос а через php пишет You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO cild(familyNumber,childName)VAL

Comment: Может, там точки с запятой перед SET не хватает?

Comment: Хватает там просто множественный запрос я же не зря писал про php  в метеке вопроса

Comment: В этом случае надо получить на стороне PHP `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` куда-то, и его вставить в качестве value для `numberFamily`, только и всего.

Comment: @Vesper нет я нашел ответ вот здесь [ссылка]http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/440490/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0   %D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-mysql-%D0%B2-php?noredirect=1#comment462708_440490      но вам спасибо все работает

Answer (score 0):

Делайте два INSERT-а, первый в родительскую таблицу, после получите id последней вставленной записи, а уже после, имея этот id делайте INSERT в дочернюю таблицу.

```
select last_insert_id( )
```

Читайте подробнее [тут](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html).

**UPD**

При использовании PDO, делай так `PDO::lastInsertId`.

При использовании Mysqli, делай так `mysqli::$insert_id`.

Использовать Mysql чистый не рекомендуют так как он не безопасный.

Comment: Ссылка на документацию - это хорошо, но все-таки надо и копировать в овтет полезную сводку, иначе ответ считается link-only answer и может быть удален.

Comment: @Vesper какая информация не достаточная? Что в ответе не так ответите? Вы хотите что бы в ответах были работающие коды? Как фриланс только фри?

Comment: Верхний абзац, который вы добавили после моего комментария (либо во время его написания), уже достаточен.

Comment: Трюк в том, что если вдруг (а в интернете может быть что угодно) документация по MySQL переедет, прочесть инфу по ссылке окажется невозможно. StackOverflow строго относится к тому, чтобы ответ был доступен хотя бы в основной части непосредственно на странице с вопросом.

Comment: @Vesper Трюк в том, что бы дублировать информацию. И вместо порождения новой информации копи пастить старую. В этом и трюк обновится MySQL сервер и будет другая документация, а что тут написано будет неверным!

Comment: посути друзья вы оба устроили свару вместо того что бы расказать о глюках last_insert_id( ) которые описаны по ссылке у меня при заполненой базе в phpmyadmin при таком запросе select last_insert_id( ) выдает следующее:  Отображение строк 0 - 1 (2 всего, Запрос занял 0.0006 сек.) вот стаками параметрами last_insert_id()
0
0

Comment: а вот что получаю если весь ваш запрос забить You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @last_id_in_catalog = LAST_INSERT_ID() INSERT INTO child(familyNumber,c' at line 2

Comment: @Sergalas Я тебе такого не писал. Подключай мозг. Делай первый запрос. После делай запрос который вернет тебе id, а потом делай второй запрос с этим id.

Comment: Я подключил мозг что интересно теперь через phpMyAdmin отрабатывается запрос а через  php  пишет You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO cild(familyNumber,childName)VAL

Comment: А перпутал тоесть делать три разных запроса ? если через select?

Comment: @Sergalas красавчик, допер. А когда из второго запроса получишь id подставишь его в 3й insert.

Comment: Да жара посто мозг плавится уже