# Множественные запросы mysql в php

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго времени суток есть вот такой запрос mysql

```
INSERT INTO catalog(name,family);
        SET @last_id_in_catalog = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        INSERT INTO child(familyNumber,childName)VALUES(@last_id_in_catalog,'$childName')
```

я его в php оформляю так

```
 <?php    $sql = "INSERT INTO catalog(name,family);
                SET @last_id_in_catalog = LAST_INSERT_ID();
                INSERT INTO child(familyNumber,childName)VALUES(@last_id_in_catalog,'$childName')"
    mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());?>
```

как вы понимаете не работает и выводит ошибку оформляю так

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$sql = "INSERT INTO catalog(name,family)VALUES("Иван",'Иванов')";
$sql .= "SET @last_id_in_catalog = LAST_INSERT_ID();";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO child(familyNumber,childName)VALUES(@last_id_in_catalog,'$childName')";
mysqli_multi_query($link, $sql);
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

ничего не делает но и ошибку не выводит. Может объясните в чем проблема? причем если через phpMyadmin отправить просто запрос то все отрабатывается.

Comment: 1. во втором примере нет вывода ошибки, почему вы ожидаете что что-то выведется?
2. сам запрос не имеет смысла, первый фрагмент запроса неполный, нет вставляемых значений.

Comment: Пропустили `;` в одном из выражений второго блока: `$sql = "INSERT INTO catalog(name,family)";`, а должно быть `$sql = "INSERT INTO catalog(name,family);";`

Comment: а как оформить вывод ошибки? Хотя бы намек? и поправил забыл values указать.

Comment: как минимум можно посмотреть что вернёт `mysqli_error()`. разбейте запросы по `;` и для каждого вызовите `mysqli_query()`, они выполняются в рамках одного соединения, сессионные переменные будут доступны. необязательно использовать multi_query

Comment: `INSERT INTO catalog(name,family);` вряд ли вообще когда-либо сработает, т.к. (дополняя первый комментарий) тут не указываются значения для вставки, и движок будет игнорировать даже значения по умолчанию.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Спасибо вы оказались прав оформите ответ я вам отмечу.

Comment: @Etki я же сказал забыл поставить VALUES("Иван",'Иванов')"; уже поправил

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Вы пропустили ; в одном из выражений второго блока. Вместо

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO catalog(name,family)VALUES('Иван','Иванов')";
```

должно быть

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO catalog(name,family)VALUES('Иван','Иванов');";
```

Comment: обещал делаю  спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> INSERT INTO catalog(name,family);
>     SET @last_id_in_catalog = LAST_INSERT_ID();
>     INSERT INTO child(familyNumber,childName)VALUES(@last_id_in_catalog,'$childName')
> ```

В данном блоке отсутствует VALUES() у первого запроса.

> ```
>  <?php    $sql = "INSERT INTO catalog(name,family);
>             SET @last_id_in_catalog = LAST_INSERT_ID();
>             INSERT INTO child(familyNumber,childName)VALUES(@last_id_in_catalog,'$childName')"
> mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());?>
> ```

В этом коде отсутствует VALUES() в конце первого запроса. Также пропущен символ `;` в конце инициализации переменной `$sql`.

> ```
> <?php
> $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db");
> $sql = "INSERT INTO catalog(name,family)VALUES("Иван",'Иванов')";
> $sql .= "SET @last_id_in_catalog = LAST_INSERT_ID();";
> $sql .= "INSERT INTO child(familyNumber,childName)VALUES(@last_id_in_catalog,'$childName')";
> mysqli_multi_query($link, $sql);
> mysqli_close($link);
> ?>
> ```

А в этом коде, во первых, пропущена `;` в первом запросе, во вторых вы используете двойные кавычки внутри двойных — это приведет к ошибке.

> ничего не делает но и ошибку не выводит...

Вы не сделали вывод ошибки. Откуда ей взяться? Используйте `mysql_error()` или `mysqli_error()`.

Всегда смотрите логи — там тоже много интересного.

Comment: Вы там правку сделали к вопросу — это решение? В смысле, исправили ошибки?

Comment: Нет, в описании к правкам я написал, что поправил кавычки в запросе и добавил VASUES в два первых блока кода — это лишь частично решает проблему автора.

Comment: И главное неправильно VALUES прописали :)

Comment: @Creamov: я к правке оставил комментарий и тут немного поясню еще. Ответ редактировать нужно только чтобы сделать его понятнее (код отформатировать например). А если это даже хотя бы частично решает проблему автора — это не вопрос уже, это ответ. Просто публикуйте исправленный код в ответе, это будет лучше всего.

Comment: @Visman ага, опечатался на двораке.

Comment: @NickVolynkin я предложил правку только потому, что автор в комментариях под вопросом сообщил "поправил, забыл values указать" — но он поправил с ошибкой (двойные кавычки внутри двойных) и поправил не везде, а только в последнем блоке кода.

Comment: @Creamov: а, вот в чем там дело. Кстати, на двораке печатаете? Сразу на нем учились или переучивались?

Comment: @NickVolynkin переучился где-то за полтора месяца; на нормальную скорость вышел еще через месяц; сейчас средняя скорость ~500 зн/мин, лучшая ~700 зн/мин. На qwerty лучшая была ~590 зн/мин.

Comment: @Creamov: хотел бы еще пару вопросов задать про дворака. Может, в чат? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26710/dvorak-russian

Answer (score -1):

Хороший программист не должен пренебрегать промежуточной отладкой и тестированием. Это значит, что хорошо бы не спешить и не пытаться инсертить **запрос неизвестно чего**. А для начала вывести запрос на экран, чтобы убедиться в его валидности и корректности.

Подавляющее количество ошибок, возникают в стремлении поскорее поднапрячь базу ТЕМ, *что получилось в результате динамической конкатенации строк*. А потом выясняется, что между параметрами забыли запятую, пропустили кавычку и т.д.

Возмите себе за правило делать `<?php echo $sql; ?>` прежде чем запрашивать непосредственно базу.

Скопируйте результат эха и попробуйте его исполнить через штатные средства СУБД. И увидите где ошибка.

Comment: Это конечно очень помогло. Не ужели вы думаете небыло print_r или var_dump?

Comment: @Sergalas содержание строки в студию!

Comment: Вы не видите что я ответ принял все уже решено как я вам уже ошибку вызову ? Вернее зачем мне это делать?

Comment: @Sergalas ну вот. Как я и предполагал – невалидный SQL-запрос. Который был бы однозначно виден на эхе.

Answer (score -3):

```
try {
    // queries to db
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    $handle = fopen(FILE, "error.txt");
    fwrite($handle, $e->getCode().': '.$e->getMessage()."\n");
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Как то так...

Желательно использовать PDO.

Comment: mysqli_* функции не выбрасывают исключений. Если бы было исключение, оно бы остановило выполнение скрипта.

Comment: @IvanSolntsev **Желательно использовать PDO.**

Comment: @ Makarenko [ссылка]http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.overview.php посмотрите внизу таблицу кому отдается предпочтение?

Comment: @IvanSolntsev я счастлив что вы умеете читать документацию, мне намного удобнее использовать PDO. Я не кого не заставлял и не убеждал в этом. Порекомендовал из личного опыта.

Comment: Вопрос не про PDO, код вопроса не будет выдавать исключений, ваш ответ будет хоть как-то относиться к вопросу, если запрос будет сделан средствами PDO.

Answer (score -3):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO catalog(name,family)");
mysql_query("SET @last_id_in_catalog = LAST_INSERT_ID()");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO child(familyNumber,childName)VALUES(@last_id_in_catalog,'$childName')");
```

Как всегда, что вопрос, что ответы, что каменты, что голосование - ад.

- mysqli выбрасывает исключения.
- но для этого запроса они не помогут
- как и mysqli_error()
- ответ Creamov не будет работать, как бы он ни вылизывал форматирование кода
- вопрос не имеет смысла
- но при этом суть вопроса не в том, как поймать ошибку
- и не в мелочном ковырянии с опечатками
- причем если бы это была опечатка, то на вопрос все равно надо не отвечать, а ставить голос о закрытии.

Модераторы, прибили бы вы этот вопрос что ли целиком. Позор ведь.

Comment: Вы считаете, что ответ из трех команд является ответом? :)

Comment: У вас невалидный SQL код в первой команде. Блок `values(...)` пропущен.

Comment: Ипатьев, жизнь боль.